# How to convert C header to Python ctypes code?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

The c-header below

```
typedef struct _node_t {
int value;
struct _node_t* next;
} node_t;
```

Can be translated like below.

```
class node_t(Structure):
    pass

node_t._fields_ = [
        ('value', ctypes.c_int),
        ('next', POINTER(node_t))
]
```

However, I can't translate the c-header codes with void and call-back functions.
How should I translate below c-header to Python c-types code?

```
class PacketHandlerDelegate_D(Structure):
pass

PacketHandlerDelegate_D._fields_ = [
    // Delegate object
    void *delegate;

    // Callback functions
    void (*addSampleToA)(void *delegate, int sample1, int sample2);
    void (*addSampleToB)(void *delegate, unsigned short int signalfast, unsigned short int signalSlow);
    void (*addSampleToC)(void *delegate, char x, char y, char z);
    void (*addSampleToD)(void *delegate, unsigned short int sample);
    void (*addSampleToE)(void *delegate, short int sample);
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation, function pointer types can be generated by [`CFUNCTYPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions). The return type `void` is signalled by `None`. `c_void_p` can be used for a void pointer.

Thus for example:

```
ADD_SAMPLE_TO_B_TYPE = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p, c_ushort, c_ushort)

...

PacketHandlerDelegate_D._fields_ = [
    ...
    (addSampleToB, ADD_SAMPLE_TO_B_TYPE),
    ...
]
```

P.S. since you don't have a recursive declaration in `PacketHandlerDelegate_D`, you can define these within the class body:

```
class PacketHandlerDelegate_D(Structure):
    ...
    addSampleToB = ADD_SAMPLE_TO_B_TYPE
    ...
```